# Irreducibility of $~\frac{x^{6k+2}-x+1}{x^2-x+1}~$ over $\mathbb Q[x]$

Tags: polynomials, factoring, irreducible-polynomials, cyclotomic-polynomials

The [Artin—Schreier polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin-Schreier_theory) $~x^n-x+1~$ is always irreducible over $\mathbb Q[x]$, unless $n=6k+2$, in which case it seems to have only two factors, one of which is always $x^2-x+1$. The irreducibility of its other factor, $$\dfrac{x^{6k+2}-x+1}{x^2-x+1}$$ holds for [all *k* lesser than $790$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reference_desk/Archives/Mathematics/2014_December_8#December_8), at the very least. My question would be whether it holds $~\forall~k\in\mathbb N$. 
 $\big($I have no formal training in abstract algebra, other than knowing the high-school definitions 
 of groups and rings: that's it. I mention this in case you are probably wondering by now about 
 the near-lack of any meaningful ideas, on my side, about how to even approach this problem. 
 I realize that I am in over my head, but the question is so interesting, that I simply could not 
 resist the temptation, and just had to ask it. Hope you will not hold it against me$\big)$. Thank you.

Comment: [Possible answer](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=61&t=623559).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, see Theorem 3 in [this paper by Ljunggren](http://www.mscand.dk/article/view/10593/8614).