# Galois group of the polynomial $x^n+x^{n-1} +⋯+x^2+x−1$

Tags: group-theory, polynomials, galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials

As we [already](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4120185) know, the following polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb Q[x]$:

$$x^n + x^{n-1} + \cdots + x^2 + x - 1 = \frac{x^{n+1} - 2x + 1 }{ x-1}.$$

By Descartes' rule of signs, it has only 1 positive real root.
It seems, though I do not know how to prove it yet, that there is only 1 real root if $n$ is odd and 2 real roots of opposite signs if $n$ is even.

Computational tests, conducted with GAP, suggest that the Galois group
of this polynomial is $S_n$. How we can actually prove it?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is perhaps possible to argue like [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwipwdDt4K3wAhXRjKQKHRo2DUgQFjABegQIAhAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcore.ac.uk%2Fdownload%2Fpdf%2F82404251.pdf&usg=AOvVaw14NBnGQpw0mekux60etsnp), where the polynomial is $x^n-x^{n-1}-\ldots -1$.

Comment: It may be that the article referred to [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3265522/11619) will help. I haven't looked it up. And in this case the trinomial is not irreducible.

Comment: It is really interesting, @DietrichBurde, the polynomial $x^n - x^{n-1} - ... - 1$ is a negative reciprocal $- x^n  f(1/x)$, where $f(x) = x^n + x^{n-1} + ... x - 1$. There should be some results about Galois group of reciprocal polynomials...

Comment: Yes, the Galois groups then are isomorphic.

Comment: @DietrichBurde could you please elaborate a little bit more why it is true or give a link to this result about reciprocal? I'm only starting to learn Galois theory and the help of specialists is priceless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The polynomial
$$
f(x)=x^n+x^{n-1}+\cdots +x^2+x-1
$$
is the negative reciprocal of the generalised Fibonacci polynomial $x^n-x^{n-1}-\cdots -x-1$. Its Galois group is indeed isomorphic to $S_n$, because both $f(x)$ and $g(x)=-x^nf(1/x)$ do have the same Galois group. The Galois group of $g(x)$ was computed in the article [The Galois group of $x^n-x^{n-1}-\cdots -x-1$](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82404251.pdf) by P. A Martin in $2004$, for even $n$ and odd prime $n$. The result is the symmetric group $S_n$. He conjectures that it is true for all $n$.

See also the article [On the Galois group of the generalised Fibonacci polynomial](https://www.anstuocmath.ro/mathematics/pdf1/cipu.ps) by Mihai Cipu and Florian Luca, which also comment on the fact that both Galois groups are isomorphic.