# Irreducibility of a family of polynomials

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Consider the following family of polynomials for every integer $d > 0$:
$$P_d(X) = X^{d+1} - X^d - 1$$
I was wondering if these were irreducible (over $\mathbb{Q}$) or not. Checking the first few hundred values of $d$ with Mathematica suggests that $P_d(X)$ is reducible iff $d \equiv 4\ (\text{mod}\ 6)$. I checked all the irreducibility criteria I know but didn't find anything that works.

**Some more information on the roots:**
These polynomials each have one positive real root $x_0\in(1,2)$ and, if $d$ is odd, one negative real root on $(-1,0)$. All other roots are non-real with modulus $<x_0$. The polynomial can easily be shown to be squarefree, so all roots are distinct.

**Possible generalisation:**
I also checked for constant terms $a_0$ other than $-1$. For $a_0 = 1$, it seems that it is reducible iff $d > 1$ and $d \equiv 1\ (\text{mod}\ 6)$. For $a_0 = 2$ it seems to be reducible for all even $d$, and if $a_0 = -2$ for all odd $d$. For $a_0$ some other non-zero integer, almost all of them seem to be irreducible except sporadically (e.g. for $a_0 = -6$ and $d = 1$ it factors and for $a_0=-4$ and $d = 2$). I mostly care about the case $a_0 = -1$ though, so I haven't thought much about these.

Comment: The irreducibility is equivalent for $-1/x^dP_d(1/X)=X^{d+1}+X-1$, and method from @KCd's answer in [Irreducibility of $x^n-x-1$ over $\mathbb Q$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/393646) should lead to the proof. I especially 
 suggest to read the comments there which refer to more details.

Comment: Indeed it does! Keith Conrad even states my case as a theorem here: https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/ringtheory/irredselmerpoly.pdf Thanks!

Comment: @Sil: If you put a link to that question and the lecture notes I linked in an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: You are welcome, turned the comments into answer with bonus reference :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The irreducibility is equivalent to that of $−X^{d+1}P_d(1/X)=X^{d+1}+X−1$, and method from Keith Conrad's answer in [Irreducibility of $x^n-x-1$ over $\mathbb Q$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/393646) should lead to the proof. Especially look at the [lecture notes](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/ringtheory/irredselmerpoly.pdf) refered in the comments there, it contains your case as a theorem.

Also one more reference, in book *Polynomials* by Victor V. Prasolov, see section **2.3.2 Irreducibility of certain trinomials**, the irreducibility of trinomials of form $x^n \pm x^m \pm 1$ is discussed.